# how to enable/disable checkbox using jQuery in primefaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, checkbox, primefaces

i am using prime faces. i have a data table having check box in each row. i want to enable/disable the check box in a particular row on some event in that row, using J Query. i want to do it on client side only. i have already used the following code : `attr('disabled', true)`
the prime faces is not allowing me to disable the check box using the above code. can anyone suggest me the possible ways of doing it? the check box should hold the current selection but user should not be allowed to change it.

Comment: use prop('disabled', true);

Comment: its also not working, is there any other solution to it?

Comment: Primefaces create a div for checkbox & the div contains 2 inner divs. First div has an input box & second div has a span inside.

Comment: You can manage selection/deselection of a dataTable rows using DataTable widgetVar.
As far as I know you cannot disable/enable one or more rows using the widgetVar, the only way to do it is using some dirty JavaScript trick.
Anyway, why don't you want to disable/enable one or more rows server side?

Answer (score -1):

we've verified through several performance tests that the traffic of HTTP requests generated by different users in the peak hour to update the server upon single checkbox selections, could impact the CPU of the application server.
Managing the single checkbox selection client-side would probably improve performance by preventing the generation of those HTTP requests.